# Codeigniter Application Apache to IIS

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, web-config, plesk

I have a codeigniter application running in Linux environment and would like to migrate it to Windows environment.

I migrated the files via FTP. The homepage worked correctly with images and styles, but the links do not and show error 404.

Does it have to do with htaccess and web.config?

Comment: so links dont work? did u hover over those links to see the url they point to? is there any difference in the links between linux/windows env?

Comment: @ilias-sp Apparently no. The link remains domain.com/test

Comment: maybe this helps? https://gist.github.com/wmandai/d28cc45f10a19eec0fcb

Comment: @Vickel still the same thing. Could it have to do with Plesk's temporary link? I am using `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/plesk-site-preview/example.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/` instead of `http://example.com` directly.

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite these links with IIS outbound rule? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by rewriting htaccess for web.config, and changing base_url.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```